# почему выдаёт ошибку sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

простая программа на Python

```py
    import sqlite3


con = sqlite3.connect("notes.db")
cur = con.cursor()
result = cur.execute("""SELECT date,
                                heading FROM main""").fetchall()
print(result)
```

но выдаёт ошибку `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table` хотя бд лежит вместе с программой

Comment: То, что бд лежит, совсем не значит, что в этой бд лежит нужная таблица.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я обращался к названию бд, которое было в самом sqllite. Обращаться надо было к названию которое лежало в папке с основной программой.

Answer (score 1):

Если дословно перевести вывод ошибки, то в ней сказано что "нет такой таблицы".
Проверьте название таблицы, может быть проблема все же в этом.